# Programmatically shutdown remote machine in Winapi

Tags: c, windows, lan

How would I go about shutting down or rebooting a system which is in same LAN, assuming I have all the necessary privileges.

Please see the code below

```
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, 
                     &tokenHandle);

    LookupPrivilegeValue("Computer name", SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, 
                         &tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Luid);

    tokenPrivileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tokenPrivileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    AdjustTokenPrivileges(tokenHandle, FALSE, &tokenPrivileges, 0, 
                         0, 0);

    switch(action)
    {
    default:
    case constEWXReboot:
    case constEWXRestartApps:
        if (!InitiateSystemShutdownEx("Computer name","Remote machine shutdown", 10, TRUE, TRUE, SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_APPLICATION))
        {
            ErrGen(constErrCannotRestartSystem);
        }
        break;
```

I am getting error code #53 The network path was not found. 
Please suggest me where i am going wrong here.

Comment: Are you really passing "Computer name" to InitiateSystemShutdownEx ?

Comment: yes, same name works with command line execution.

Comment: I would have thought it would at least need to be "\\\\Computer name" ?

Comment: @PaulR i tried all possible ways but still i am getting the same error,so if you know any other method please let me know

Comment: hi guys it works only when both the machines are logged in as a administrator or by providing impersonation password.

Answer (score 4):

[InitiateSystemShutdownEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874(v=vs.85).aspx)  win API function will do this.

> **Initiates a shutdown and optional restart of the specified computer, and optionally records the reason for the shutdown.**
>
> To shut down the local computer, the calling thread must have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. To shut down a remote computer, the calling thread must have the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on the remote computer. By default, users can enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on the computer they are logged onto, and administrators can enable the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on remote computers.

Comment: Hi johnny i tried what you suggested but i am getting network path was not found

Comment: May be it's because you provide wrong path to remote computer? What is exact name of the machine you are trying to shut down?
Try InitiateSystemShutdownEx("\\\\Computer name", ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an API - you can just invoke `shutdown.exe` via a call to `system()`, e.g.:

```
system("shutdown -r -f -t 00 -m \\\\computername");
```

Comment: this is working only through command prompt not in my code, i hard coded and checked still it didn't work

Comment: we are using different type of coding method so its better not to post that here ,sorry for that.

Comment: You don't have to post the whole program - just post the code fragment where you are trying to invoke shutdown - otherwise unless people can see your code no one can help you to fix it.

Comment: Above method didn't work so i tried with the above code and now i am getting network path not found,so if u have any clues suggest me the same